# Basis of solution space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the basis of the solution space of this system?

$$x_1-2x_2+2x_3-x_4=3$$
$$3x_1+x_2+6x_3+11x_4=16$$
$$2x_1-x_2+4x_3+4x_4=9$$

I got the solution set easily enough:$$\{(5,1,0,0)+s(-2,0,1,0)+t(-3,-2,0,1):s,t\in\mathbb R\}$$

What is the basis of the solution space then? It can't be the set of those three vectors (can it?) because the solutions aren't a linear combination of $\{(5,1,0,0),(-2,0,1,0),(-3,-2,0,1)\}$. They are a linear combination of $\{(-2,0,1,0),(-3,-2,0,1)\}$ *plus* $(5,1,0,0)$.

Comment: Right. You cannot provide a basis since it is not a subspace.

Comment: Find the solution to the associated homogeneous (=0) system.  That is a vector subspace.  Then, translate this by any solution to the system.  Et voila! You have the general solution.  I can see you have all of this.

Comment: The set of solutions of a non-homogeneous linear system us only an affine subspace.